# Rails detect if user is login from multiple devises

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Devise, and I want to detect if user login from other device. (I don't want to restrict second session, so devise secure extension won't work).

So the question is - how to detect if user login from multiple devices in same time.

Comment: You would need to modify the sessions controller to store logins on a separate table and identify them by something like the IP or MAC address and also store the user id. You can then get the "logins" by querying the table.

Comment: html request don't have Mac address (so you can't get it from user_agent)

Comment: And ip can be changed, if user is log in from cafe, work or home (or mobile phone). So this method will return more bugs than, it will have use

Comment: Dude, I'm just saying that you need to use some sort of identifier and link it to a user. You'll have to figure out the details. You can use the `session.id` since the cookie is unique per device.

Comment: You need to detect what sessions ids are currently used by the user. If there are more than one active (you recieive requests with them alternately).

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the device with [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2). When the user logs, store the fingerprint in the session and query the session store if the user is on a new device or not.

Comment: We store our sessions on server side. The purpose, is to detect two log in from one account is same time and send email, if user logged in twice or more from same account.

Comment: What is the current session store? A db store or a cache store like redis?

Comment: Also, what is preferred to happen if a user clears their cookies or closes their browser without logging out? Should they still get the same email?

Comment: 1. We store session in DB
2. I thought about it, ofc no, user should not receive email, but I don't think it's possible to control (only if we send cookies to user, and my device count method must check if there is this cookie or delete device record)